# Javascript AES encryption

Tags: javascript, encryption, aes

Is there a library available for AES 256-bits encryption in Javascript?

Comment: Here is what you need for AES encryption using crypto-js  
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/aes.js"></script>

<script>
    var encryptedAES = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("Message", "Passphrase");      
    var decrypted    = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptedAES.toString(), "Passphrase");
    console.log("Encrypted: ", encryptedAES.toString());
    console.log("Decrypted: ", decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
</script>

Comment: There is also the Stanford Javascript Crypto Library (SJCL): https://crypto.stanford.edu/sjcl/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18279141/javascript-string-encryption-and-decryption

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/encrypt

Answer (score 71, accepted):

JSAES is a powerful implementation of AES in JavaScript.
http://point-at-infinity.org/jsaes/

Comment: JSAES is licensed under GNU GPL - therefore it is not usable for some projects.

Comment: How can I specify a 'mode of operation' and IV?  Doesn't look like it's an option.

Comment: This is now quite useful and feature rich http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/

Comment: @HappyDeveloper 
Well, no. Don't blame the license for this. The author has chosen the wrong license, as GPL is not suitable for libraries.

Comment: You can use: https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge under a BSD license.

Comment: What's wrong with GPL license? It is still free to use.

Comment: It's "free of cost to use", but you can't use it if you want to release your resulting product under something other than the GPL.

Comment: If you argue the library to be sufficiently disconnected you can use it. Not sure how the courts feel about that (anyone have a source?)

Comment: **JSAES** is a good starting point but it can be used only to encrypt 16 bytes of data. If you want to encrypt bigger block of data you have to extend it yourself to implement intialization vector, encrypt mode (CBC or other...), padding.

Comment: Source Code: http://point-at-infinity.org/jsaes/jsaes.js   < 200 lines.   Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: ```The code is well documented and the API trivial. ``` - I want to send a sensitive data to a friend over email. We've already established a shared secret *(offline, handwritten)* - why usability of crypto is so 1994?

Comment: @MarsRobertson When I first saw that line, I laughed so hard. This is what every programmer thinks of their own work. But I did actually try it, and the API was indeed trivial. Maybe a little too trivial for something like AES. Before serious use, JSAES ought to be extended to use IV, etc.

Answer (score 38):

Here's [a demonstration page](http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/AES-Encryption.htm) that uses slowAES.

[slowAES](http://code.google.com/p/slowaes) was easy to use. Logically designed.  Reasonable OO packaging.  Supports knobs and levers like IV and Encryption mode.  Good compatibility with .NET/C#.  The name is tongue-in-cheek; it's called "**slow** AES" because it's not implemented in C++.  But in my tests it was not impractically slow.

It lacks an ECB mode. Also lacks a CTR mode, although you could build one pretty easily given an ECB mode, I guess.

It is solely focused on encryption. A nice complementary class that does [RFC2898](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2898.txt)-compliant password-based key derivation, in Javascript, is [available from Anandam](http://anandam.name/pbkdf2/).  This pair of libraries works well with the analogous .NET classes.  Good interop. Though, in contrast to SlowAES, the Javascript PBKDF2 is noticeably slower than the [Rfc2898DeriveBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx) class when generating keys.

It's not surprising that technically there is good interop, but the key point for me was the model adopted by SlowAES is familiar and easy to use. I found some of the other Javascript libraries for AES to be hard to understand and use.  For example, in some of them I couldn't find the place to set the IV, or the mode (CBC, ECB, etc).  Things were not where I expected them to be.   SlowAES was not like that. The properties were right where I expected them to be. It was easy for me to pick up, having been familiar with the Java and .NET crypto programming models.

Anandam's PBKDF2 was not quite on that level. It supported only a single call to DeriveBytes function, so if you need to derive both a key and an IV from a password, this library won't work, unchanged.  Some slight modification, and it is working just fine for that purpose.

**EDIT**: I put together [an example](http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/srcview.aspx?dir=AES-example) of packaging [SlowAES](http://code.google.com/p/slowaes) and a modified version of Anandam's [PBKDF2](http://anandam.name/pbkdf2/) into Windows Script Components.  Using this AES with a password-derived key shows good interop with the .NET RijndaelManaged class.

**EDIT2**: [the demo page](http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/AES-Encryption.htm) shows how to use this AES encryption from a web page.  Using the same inputs (iv, key, mode, etc) supported in .NET gives you good interop with the .NET Rijndael class. You can do a "view source" to get the javascript for that page.

**EDIT3**
a late addition: [Javascript Cryptography considered harmful.](https://web.archive.org/web/20160323100711/https://www.nccgroup.trust/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2011/august/javascript-cryptography-considered-harmful/) Worth the read.

Comment: +1 for [JavaScript Cryptography considered harmful](https://web.archive.org/web/20160323100711/https://www.nccgroup.trust/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2011/august/javascript-cryptography-considered-harmful/)

Comment: I see one valid use-case - HTML 5 app in which all files are stored localy. If local files can be hijacked then your doomed in any case ;-).

Comment: about edit3 link, it is a piece of crap of an article... half of its statements are completely false!

Comment: I hate when everyone fails to mention that ssl/tls is not a secure protocol, but in fact prone to attacks, especially from goverments which all serious security statements should ultimately consider. If you can't trust the NSA or the certificate provider, how can I ensure security between the user and my server? Further more, the user should also be protected against me, the server! I believe ssl/tls + javascript encryption is the way to go, and the motivitaion is secure javascript delivery + isolated private and public key generation.

Comment: The random key problem can be addressed by having the user move the mouse and enter keys as a true random generator.

Comment: The link to the demonstration page appears to be broken.

Comment: Also the link to the JS demo page in the slowAES page is broken, and there doesn't seem to be any documentation at all.

Comment: A clear working example of slowaes would be very useful... all the links are broken.

Comment: @MikePennington the article says: "You could use SSL/TLS to solve this problem, but that's expensive and complicated." What did I missed?^^

Comment: @MartinPfeffer I don't understand the question; please provide more context or better still ask a new question referencing this one

Comment: @momomo the article responds to your comment about JavaScript cryptography + TLS.  Your task would be defeating the arguments already made against browser hosted cryptographic code listed in the article

Answer (score 31):

In my searches for AES encryption i found this from some Standford students.  Claims to be fastest out there. Supports CCM, OCB, GCM and Block encryption.
http://crypto.stanford.edu/sjcl/

Comment: thats what I am talkin about!

Comment: Documentation is lacking, and it's hard to use. How do you change key length? I hunted round the docs and couldn't figure it out in a reasonable time. Also when you encrypt something you get an array of key-value pairs returned, but the docs don't seem to explain these. I ended up using the movable type library.

Comment: And this is not async so if you are encrypting or decrypting some longer string for example with AES-CBC, then it blocks the UI

Answer (score 13):

[Googling "JavaScript AES"](http://www.google.com/search?q=JavaScript+AES) has found several examples. The first one that popped up is designed to explain the algorithm as well as provide a solution:

[Movable Type Scripts: AES](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/aes.html)

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to set the IV in that library.  Also it's not very OO.

Comment: The equivalent of the IV in counter mode is the nonce. This implementation has been reformulated to be more OO. It does only include counter (CTR) mode of operation.

Comment: This works pretty well, except it doesn't have any ECB mode.

Comment: Googling it also shows up this question as the second result.

Comment: You'll have to forgive me; this answer is 12 years old, and Stack Overflow didn't show up on Google very often when I wrote it. :-)

Answer (score 12):

This post is now old, but the [crypto-js](http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/), may be now the most complete javascript encryption library.

[CryptoJS](http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/) is a collection of cryptographic algorithms implemented in JavaScript. 
It includes the following cyphers: AES-128, AES-192, AES-256, DES, Triple DES, Rabbit, RC4, RC4Drop and hashers: MD5, RIPEMD-160, SHA-1, SHA-256, SHA-512, SHA-3 with 224, 256, 384, or 512 bits.

You may want to look at their [Quick-start Guide](http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#Quick-start_Guide) which is also the reference for the following node.js port.

[node-cryptojs-aes](https://npmjs.org/package/node-cryptojs-aes) is a node.js port of [crypto-js](http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/)

Comment: Unfortunately the documentation is lacking. It only seems to have a 'quick start' guide. Where is the full documentation? It says it supports multiple key lengths, but no documentation on how to do that.

Comment: @CpnCrunch : the full API doc is not online, but the code as full javadoc api comments. And you can generate it. Read the comments on [cipher-core.js source](http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/source/browse/tags/3.1.2/src/cipher-core.js) youl find cipher's key size and cipher's IV size.

Comment: weird, when i encrypt and decrypt back, the texts are different

Comment: There are some conflicts because of use openssl

Answer (score 9):

Recently I had the need to perform some encryption/decryption interoperability between javascript and python.

Specifically...

1) Using AES to encrypt in javascript and decrypt in python (Google App Engine)
2) Using RSA to encrypt in javascript and decrypt in python (Google App Engine)
3) Using pycrypto

I found lots and lots of different versions of RSA and AES floating around the web and 
they were all different in their approach but I did not find a good example of end to end javascript and python interoperability.

Eventually I managed to cobble together something that suited my needs after a lot of trial and error.

Anyhow I knocked up an example of a js/webapp talking to a google app engine hosted python server that uses AES and public key and private key RSA stuff.

I though I'd include it here by link in case it will be of some use to others who need to accomplish the same thing.

http://www.ipowow.com/files/aesrsademo.tar.gz

and see **demo** at rsa-aes-demo DOT appspot DOT com

edit: look at the browser console output and also view source to get some hints and useful messages as to what's going on in the **demo**

edit: updated very old and defunct link to source to now point to

https://sestertii.com/files/aesrsademo.tar.gz

Comment: Thank you SO much for this! I couldn't for the life of me get my javascript aes to talk to my python aes.

Comment: I've been trying all night (with pycrypto and others) to do what your code helped me accomplish in 10 minutes. Thank you SO much!

Comment: For whatever reason I got RSA working easily but AES is a royal pain. Thank you for this!!!

Comment: the link ... is not found!

Answer (score 8):

Judging from my own experience, [asmcrypto.js](https://github.com/vibornoff/asmcrypto.js) provides the fastest AES implementation in JavaScript (especially in Firefox since it can fully leverage asm.js there).

From the readme:

> ```
> Chrome/31.0
> SHA256: 51 MiB/s (9 times faster than SJCL and CryptoJS)
> AES-CBC: 47 MiB/s (13 times faster than CryptoJS and 20 times faster than SJCL)
>
> Firefox/26.0
> SHA256: 144 MiB/s (5 times faster than CryptoJS and 20 times faster than SJCL)
> AES-CBC: 81 MiB/s (3 times faster than CryptoJS and 8 times faster than SJCL)
> ```

**Edit:** The [Web Cryptography API](http://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI) is now [implemented in most browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=web%20crypto) and should be used as the primary solution if you care about performance. Be aware that IE11 implemented an earlier draft version of the standard which did not use promises.

Some examples can be found here:

- [Web Cryptography API Examples on GitHub](https://github.com/diafygi/webcrypto-examples)
- [Deriving Keys from Passwords with WebCrypto](http://blog.engelke.com/2015/02/14/deriving-keys-from-passwords-with-webcrypto/)

Comment: I'm getting about 8 MiB/s with CryptoJS. Wonder how this would perform.

Answer (score 7):

Use CryptoJS

Here's the code:
https://github.com/odedhb/AES-encrypt

And here's an online working example:
https://odedhb.github.io/AES-encrypt/

Comment: the best answer

Comment: I'm not sure if understood, but your "the code" is different from "online working example" (and "the code" seemed not to work at least in part). Anyway, helped me here. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Try [asmcrypto.js](https://github.com/vibornoff/asmcrypto.js) — it's really fast.

PS: I'm an author and I can answer your questions if any.
Also I'd be glad to get some feedback :)

Comment: asmcrypto.js is nice, but on IE10 its not works well. it hangs browser for more than 1 min sometimes, or at least 45 sec. Plus, I didn't understand, why you need to replace global Math function? there are lot of libraries which use this one.

Comment: Could you comment on how you're sure it's working properly? IOW: How do you know you implemented AES properly?

Comment: IE10 performance is poor due to it doesn't optimize asm.js at all. Also it has a bit different JIT patterns. Making the code work well in IE also makes it suck in Chrome and FF. Suppose I had right choice.

Regarding to _Math.random_ there was a long [discussion](https://github.com/vibornoff/asmcrypto.js/issues/27). Shortly speaking this need for prevention of raw _Math.random_ output leakage (wich in theory may degrade PRNG security).

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to use javascript to avoid using SSL, think again. There are many half-way measures, but **only** SSL provides secure communication. Javascript encryption libraries can help against a certain set of attacks, but not a true man-in-the-middle attack.

The following article explains how to attempt to create secure communication with javascript, and how to get it wrong:
[Use JavaScript encryption module instead of SSL/HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145147/use-javascript-encryption-module-instead-of-ssl-https/9930665#9930665)

*Note*: If you are looking for SSL for google app engine on a custom domain, take a look at [wwwizer.com](http://wwwizer.com/).

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted to oblivion, as it is a very good point that anyone thinking of implementing javascript encryption needs to at the very least consider.  Upvoted.

Comment: Using client side crypto to avoid SSL is an old point which some people say to go against it: in fact it can add security to HTTPS, avoiding passive attacks, or be used in downloaded applications and browser extensions. I just saw once it being used wrong (my college, but they already fixed it) and many times used right (cryptocat, as a example).

Answer (score 3):

There is also a Stanford free lib as an alternative to Cryptojs

http://crypto.stanford.edu/sjcl/

Answer (score 2):

http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/aes.html library may be of some help.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution w/AES-256 support: https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge

Answer (score 2):

Here is the only solution that worked for me:

http://www.hanewin.net/encrypt/aes/aes.htm

It's pretty basic, but simple to use and seems to work well.

Comment: How do you actually call the encrypt and decrypt function?

Comment: https://www.hanewin.net/encrypt/aes/aes-test.htm