# Protecting the sources of HTML5 game

Tags: javascript, html

People have been saying so many good words for HTML5, but one of my main concern is how to protect the source code of my game.

essentially..

1. How to prevent other from using our own developed game engine (that's a huge assets)
2. How to prevent other from downloading the game and host it in other platform
3. How to hide the server API calls detail in the sources, e.g. our own scoreboard API, virtual currency API etc.

Comment: You've got answers all basically saying "You can't stop this", but note that that only applies to the _client-side_ components of your game. The _server-side_ components are safe. So people will be able to see the requests/responses to/from your server API, but they won't be able to see how the API is implemented on the server.

Comment: @nnnnnn well, to be perfectly clear, you can get a lot of information from how API calls work and if you really want you could build on that. A lof of online games (such as WoW etc) have unofficial servers. You can hide the exact implementation, but not functionality.

Comment: If you use node-WebKit it will compile your game to an exe in windows.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"You can't" is the answer to all 3 questions. The only thing you can do is to slow down whoever's interested in your code by ofuscating it, but ultimately, if somebody wants to use your code, there's nothing you can do about it.

Answer (score 7):

i personally use **Google Closure Compiler** with advanced compression to **obfuscate** my code (download the Java-file, don't use the online-version!). It takes some extra effort to prepare the code but it's all very well docmented and once you understood how the compiler works it's really easy to comply with its rules. It not only obfuscates your code but actually optimizes it for execution speed and file size as well.

to be clear - yes the other guys are right, no ultimate protection... bla bla. BUT: ever tried to make heads or tails of googles JavaScript? I tried and failed. If you use obfuscated class-names and very few strings in your code it will be very hard to read, meaning it might takes months depending on the complexity of your code.

For API-calls things are different. encryption won't work as the decryption code will be visible within the javascript - even with obfuscation that part will be hard to hide as AJAX code always looks a bit alike... Also encryption uses up CPU time which you probably need elsewhere. Deferring is one way but in the end, API-calls will be more or less readable.

Answer (score 7):

Obfuscating your javascript code could be one important step. Obfuscation can make the code so complex that no sane person would try to hack it.

I have been using [jscrambler.com](https://jscrambler.com/html5) with good results. That said, obfuscation will not solve every problem. Users will still be able to view all the traffic exchanged between the browser and the server. So they will know how the API works and how to use it.

To avoid this you can use encryption of messages using javascript. This could be helpful in securing the content. I found a post on stackoverflow that discuss encryption using javascript: [Javascript AES encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793812/javascript-aes-encryption). There are a few implementations that can be used that have a low performance impact.

Last but not least, all inputs should be thoroughly checked on the server side. All logic that can be implemented on the server side should remain there.

Answer (score 4):

You could run your game on a touch screen pc in secure hardware cabinet (like at an Airport) and not make it accessible via the internet. Maybe not the ideal answer you were looking for though.

Comment: +1 for being both inside a box and yet outside the box

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately, there is no protection of assets on the web. If you can see it in a browser, you can download it with curl. If protection of assets is a major concern for you, I don't recommend HTML and JavaScript.

You can obfuscate your code to prevent casual theft and use SSL to prevent snooping, but industrious people will still be able to access these assets in other ways.

Comment: SSL will not prevent snooping. HTTP proxies (like Fiddler2) will allow you to set up a man in the middle so that it can decrypt all traffic sent from your computer (through the local proxy) to the host.

Answer (score 0):

Minifying your js code will make it much harder to reuse but not impossible

Comment: Minifying your js code will make it much harder to reuse but not impossible
you can prettify the js right into the chrome dev tools , so minifying should only by a matter of performances

Answer (score 0):

There is no physical ways to copy protect digital files. Many industries have tried. Many have failed. Sadly, many will continue to try and continue to fail, but business seems to have trouble learning from their past mistakes at times.

Best to not focus too much on that. Focus on your customers.

Answer (score 0):

Was asking myself the same question in 2019 as am developing on Babylon....till today there is no bulletproof method to do this, BUT you CAN minimize your risk exposure by getting visitors to register as users , and protect your game code behind a login-level access.