# to hide variable in form of php

Tags: php

As we know, passing $_POST['foo'] is the safest one on php.
even we want to pass variable without the end user notice, we can use `<input type='hidden'>`,
but too bad, even user with basic knowledge can notice this by inspecting elements (chrome) or show source code and change the value.

is there any way to encrypt or hide this value, so i can pass this 'secretly' parameter to the action page? javascript perhaps?

Comment: Store it in the session instead ?

Comment: or encrypt the value? what kind of value do you want to pass anyway? does it matter if the user sees it (if he really takes the hassle to look in the source)?

Comment: As you clearly don't know, `$_POST` isn't _much_ safer than `$_GET`, check `$_SESSION`

Comment: @Alex-Info.net yes, and save it on the database? its a bit complex (for me) on my way looking for example. thanks though

Comment: @giorgio like some value that want to be passed through 2 pages. it is matter, when they can change the value.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem yes, i'd notice that, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want a value to be secret, don't let it leave the server to begin with. Store secret values on the server only and give the client some *token* that lets him refer to the value without actually giving the value itself away.

The classic and most used example of this is a session, in which the user receives only a meaningless session id and all data associated with that session id is stored server side.

Comment: oh, that's the way it goes.. we save the value of some variables on database? like retrieve token to get some value? thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can submit the form using HTTPS to prevent anyone else from seeing the traffic.

To prevent your user from seeing it, you could encode the value using JavaScript. For example, using [AES encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793812/javascript-aes-encryption) or a simple [base64 conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-a-string-to-base64-in-javascript). Of course, you will need corresponding code on the PHP side to decode the value. I am not sure this is the best overall approach though, since a savvy user could still read your JavaScript and figure out what is going on - as deceze wrote, any value that is submitted to the client is no longer secret.

Comment: that's what i thought, when javascript loads, i give everything to them tough... anyway, thanks!