# JavaScript string encryption and decryption?

Tags: encryption, javascript

I'm interested in building a small app for personal use that will encrypt and decrypt information on the client side using JavaScript.  The encrypted information will be stored in a database on a server, but never the decrypted version.

It doesn't have to be super duper secure, but I would like to use a currently unbroken algorithm.

Ideally I'd be able to do something like

```
var gibberish = encrypt(string, salt, key);
```

to generate the encoded string, and something like

```
var sensical = decrypt(gibberish, key);
```

to decode it later.

So far I've seen this:
http://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/

Any other libraries I should look at?

Comment: Take a look at [Javascript AES encryption](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793812/javascript-aes-encryption)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kein1945/M9K2c/

Comment: Some terminology here is off, Here's a simple version  

1. Salts are added to information (usually passwords) being hashed. Their purpose is to make the hash different than it would be without the salt. This is useful because it makes pre-generated of hashes if your database gets hacked and hashed user passwords get out.  

2. Hashing is a one-way operation that translates input into output. It cannot be easily reversed or undone.  

3. Encoding is not encryption. base64_encode, urlencode, etc.

Comment: I struggled to find that nowadays we have something like `window.crypto` natively. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/encrypt

Answer (score 244):

```js
 var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("Message", "Secret Passphrase");
//U2FsdGVkX18ZUVvShFSES21qHsQEqZXMxQ9zgHy+bu0=

var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, "Secret Passphrase");
//4d657373616765


document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = encrypted;
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = decrypted;
document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
```

```html
Full working sample actually is:

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/aes.js" integrity="sha256-/H4YS+7aYb9kJ5OKhFYPUjSJdrtV6AeyJOtTkw6X72o=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<br><br>
<label>encrypted</label>
<div id="demo1"></div>
<br>

<label>decrypted</label>
<div id="demo2"></div>

<br>
<label>Actual Message</label>
<div id="demo3"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Tomas. Do you know of the encrypted sting is guaranteed to be compatible JavaScript?

Comment: Encrypted is actually an object, but you can call encrypted.toString() to get the string. You will be able to decrypt that string later: http://jsbin.com/kofiqokoku/1/

Comment: But how can we secure the Secret passphrase?

Comment: It's up to you where you store and how you retrieve that secret passphrase. Sample just shows how to use it.

Comment: It seems crypto js is an archived project. There is a clone on github: https://github.com/sytelus/CryptoJS but it hasn't been updated in two years. Is this still the best option for js encryption?

Comment: I would go with this one: https://github.com/brix/crypto-js it is also available via NPM

Comment: But how can this encrypted message further decrypted by the NodeJS? I mean if client side Javascript encrypt information like you mentioned, then if we pass it to Nodejs server app, then what will be its code? I think we can use 'crypto' module but what will be exact code? I tried on my end but have not been successful.

Comment: @TomasKirda , May I know how would you store and retrieve the `Secret passphrase` ?

Comment: @stom it is up to you how and where you store it. I don't know if there is truly secure way to store it in a browser. Request them from the server and store in memory.

Comment: @Tomas Kirda I think this sums up client side encryption perfectly. 
You cannot securely store the key on the client. 
This is impossible, which makes client side encryption, dangerous.

Comment: @duykhoa You don't do it this way. This solution is only secure, if the secret passphrase will be entered by the user. I.e. you could use this method to allow the user to setup a shorter password to recover a session and encrypt the permanent session token locally for storage this way, so the client is protected against physical third party access, when the temporary session is closed. If you want to use PIN protection it falls flat again, though, because they are too easy to bruteforce.

Answer (score 99):

I created an insecure but simple text cipher/decipher utility. No dependencies with any external library.

These are the functions:

```js
const cipher = salt => {
    const textToChars = text => text.split('').map(c => c.charCodeAt(0));
    const byteHex = n => ("0" + Number(n).toString(16)).substr(-2);
    const applySaltToChar = code => textToChars(salt).reduce((a,b) => a ^ b, code);

    return text => text.split('')
      .map(textToChars)
      .map(applySaltToChar)
      .map(byteHex)
      .join('');
}
    
const decipher = salt => {
    const textToChars = text => text.split('').map(c => c.charCodeAt(0));
    const applySaltToChar = code => textToChars(salt).reduce((a,b) => a ^ b, code);
    return encoded => encoded.match(/.{1,2}/g)
      .map(hex => parseInt(hex, 16))
      .map(applySaltToChar)
      .map(charCode => String.fromCharCode(charCode))
      .join('');
}

// To create a cipher
const myCipher = cipher('mySecretSalt')

//Then cipher any text:
console.log(myCipher('the secret string'))

//To decipher, you need to create a decipher and use it:
const myDecipher = decipher('mySecretSalt')
console.log(myDecipher("7c606d287b6d6b7a6d7c287b7c7a61666f"))
```

Comment: let myDecipher = decipher('CartelSystem') - This salt will decipher the string as well. You don't have to know the exact word 'mySecretSalt'

Comment: Also, is saltChars in decipher not being used?

Comment: I think you should convert this code to a simple `npm` package. It's really helpful!! Just finished using it in React app, after few workarounds :)

Comment: Yet another post where someone is blindly using `let`. ︎

Comment: The length of `byteHex` should be extended to `4` since the maximum `charCode` is `2^16 - 1(i.e. 65535)`, which will be `ffff` when encoded to base 16. Fix: `const byteHex = n => ("000" + Number(n).toString(16)).substr(-4);` and `return encoded => encoded.match(/.{1,4}/g)`

Comment: Isn't this a) super broken and insecure and b) the 'salt' is in fact your 'secret key' as salts are not expected to be private?
I think its very dangerous to post code like this without any comments that this fun-code not intended for any real world use. The amount of upvotes is worrisome.
https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/11466/randomly-generated-key-reused-with-xor

Comment: Hi @Ishmierer, thanks for your comment. As you say it is fun code. But it is not less secure than the other two most upvoted answers, in which a secret-phrase (my salt) is exposed.

This is JS code, but can be used in nodejs or in the browser, where your can cipher a message before sending it to an storage or REST endpoint.

Comment: Well at least they use sound crypto. What you are doing is basically a Caesar Chipher (applying the same key to every character) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher#Breaking_the_cipher
Regarding the other answers... I expect it to be obvious that something called a "secret" is expected to be kept secret (by the user)

Comment: It would be nice if we can get C# version of it, especially decipher, as it is more needed on Server where we will receive Encrypted version of password.

Comment: Simple and best solution if you modify it to be used secure in your app, of course. This was useful for little securities like cipher addresses and user's personal information and store in the DB. This is better than let all these sensitive informations wide open and visible. Furthermore it is the most performant solution. Thanks!

Comment: @SeanC. I agree, 4-byte UTF strings like emojis `` are not decoded well.

Comment: First, it is a simple substitution cipher based on whatever 8 bit number comes out of textToChars(salt), which is weak to start with, but if the value of that function happens to be zero then the bytes that come out are the hex ascii values of what you are trying to encrypt. For instance, if you use salt = "ABC123p" then textToChars(salt) = 0 and if you encrypt "the secret string" you get out 74 68 65 20 73 65 63 72 65 74 20 73 74 72 69 6E 67 which is the same as if you typed that phrase into https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/ascii-to-hex.html

Answer (score 98):

How about [CryptoJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js)?

It's a solid crypto library, with a lot of functionality. It implements hashers, HMAC, PBKDF2 and ciphers. In this case ciphers is what you need. Check out the quick-start quide on the project's homepage.

You could do something like with the AES:

```
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/aes.js"></script>

<script>
    var encryptedAES = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("Message", "My Secret Passphrase");
    var decryptedBytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptedAES, "My Secret Passphrase");
    var plaintext = decryptedBytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
</script>
```

As for security, at the moment of my writing AES algorithm is thought to be unbroken

**Edit :**

Seems online URL is down & you can use the downloaded files for encryption from below given link & place the respective files in your root folder of the application.

https://code.google.com/archive/p/crypto-js/downloads

or used other CDN like https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/components/aes-min.js

Comment: What is the difference between rollups and components under folder 3.1.2?

Comment: After playing a bit the components are the separated parts. You will need to know which components to take (and in what order) to make it work. The rollups files contain everything you need to make it work with just one script reference (much better as the hard job is already done).

Comment: But how can we secure the Secret passphrase ?

Comment: @shaijut You don't. You don't even save it anywhere except in RAM when encrypting/decrypting the plaintext. The passphrase should only be stored in the user's brain (or a password manager)

Answer (score 56):

### This code is based on @Jorgeblom's answer above.

---

@Jorgeblom my man, that's fantastic small crypto lib :D
I touch it a bit because I didn't like that I have to assign the salt and to call it again but in general, for my needs is absolutely perfect.

```
const crypt = (salt, text) => {
  const textToChars = (text) => text.split("").map((c) => c.charCodeAt(0));
  const byteHex = (n) => ("0" + Number(n).toString(16)).substr(-2);
  const applySaltToChar = (code) => textToChars(salt).reduce((a, b) => a ^ b, code);

  return text
    .split("")
    .map(textToChars)
    .map(applySaltToChar)
    .map(byteHex)
    .join("");
};

const decrypt = (salt, encoded) => {
  const textToChars = (text) => text.split("").map((c) => c.charCodeAt(0));
  const applySaltToChar = (code) => textToChars(salt).reduce((a, b) => a ^ b, code);
  return encoded
    .match(/.{1,2}/g)
    .map((hex) => parseInt(hex, 16))
    .map(applySaltToChar)
    .map((charCode) => String.fromCharCode(charCode))
    .join("");
};
```

And you use it

```
// encrypting
const encrypted_text = crypt("salt", "Hello"); // -> 426f666665

// decrypting
const decrypted_string = decrypt("salt", "426f666665"); // -> Hello
```

Comment: you did a great job

Comment: Thanks, Hamza but as much as I'd like to take credit, @Jorgeblom did the real job :)

Comment: What is the equivalent for PHP?

Comment: Thanks, it's a simple version that uses string only. Pretty useful :D

Comment: Does not work on other characters (like spaces)

Comment: how safe is this and what parts need to be kept secret? can the source code be publicly visible...

Comment: It also decrypt when salt is in reverse order.

Comment: First, it is a simple substitution cipher based on whatever 8 bit number comes out of textToChars(salt), which is weak to start with, but if the value of that function happens to be zero then the bytes that come out are the hex ascii values of what you are trying to encrypt. For instance, if you use salt = "ABC123p" then textToChars(salt) = 0 and if you encrypt "the secret string" you get out 74 68 65 20 73 65 63 72 65 74 20 73 74 72 69 6E 67 which is the same as if you typed that phrase into rapidtables.com/convert/number/ascii-to-hex.html

Answer (score 29):

The existing answers which leverage SJCL, CryptoJS, and/or WebCrypto aren't *necessarily wrong* but they're not as safe as you might initially suspect. Generally you want to [use libsodium](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/09/how-to-safely-implement-cryptography-in-any-application). First I'll explain why, then how.

## Why Not SJCL, CryptoJS, WebCrypto, etc.?

**Short answer:** In order for your encryption to actually be secure, these libraries expect you to make too many choices e.g. the block cipher mode (CBC, CTR, GCM; if you can't tell which of the three I just listed is secure to use and under what constraints, you shouldn't be burdened with this sort of choice *at all*).

Unless your job title is *cryptography engineer*, the odds are stacked against you implementing it securely.

### Why to Avoid CryptoJS?

CryptoJS offers a handful of building blocks and expects you to know how to use them securely. [It even defaults to CBC mode](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#block-modes-and-padding) ([archived](https://archive.fo/uBsBQ)).

#### Why is CBC mode bad?

Read [this write-up on AES-CBC vulnerabilities](https://robertheaton.com/2013/07/29/padding-oracle-attack/).

### Why to Avoid WebCrypto?

WebCrypto is a potluck standard, designed by committee, for purposes that are orthogonal to cryptography engineering. Specifically, [WebCrypto was meant to replace Flash, not provide security](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=13821347).

### Why to Avoid SJCL?

SJCL's public API and documentation begs users to encrypt data with a human-remembered password. This is rarely, if ever, what you want to do in the real world.

Additionally: Its default PBKDF2 round count is roughly [86 times as small as you want it to be](https://www.nccgroup.trust/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2015/march/enough-with-the-salts-updates-on-secure-password-schemes/). AES-128-CCM is probably fine.

Out of the three options above, SJCL is the least likely to end in tears. But there are better options available.

## Why is Libsodium Better?

You don't need to choose between a menu of cipher modes, hash functions, and other needless options. You'll never [risk screwing up your parameters and removing all security from your protocol](https://www.cryptofails.com/post/70059600123/saltstack-rsa-e-d-1).

Instead, [libsodium](https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/) just gives you simple options tuned for maximum security and minimalistic APIs.

- `crypto_box()` / `crypto_box_open()` offer authenticated public-key encryption.

  - The algorithm in question combines X25519 (ECDH over Curve25519) and XSalsa20-Poly1305, but you don't need to know (or even care) about that to use it securely
- `crypto_secretbox()` / `crypto_secretbox_open()` offer shared-key authenticated encryption.

  - The algorithm in question is XSalsa20-Poly1305, but you don't need to know/care

Additionally, libsodium has [bindings in dozens of popular programming languages](https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/bindings_for_other_languages), so it's very likely that libsodium will **just work** when trying to interoperate with another programming stack. Also, libsodium tends to be very fast without sacrificing security.

## How to Use Libsodium in JavaScript?

First, you need to decide one thing:

1. Do you just want to encrypt/decrypt data (and maybe still somehow use the plaintext in database queries securely) and not worry about the details? Or...
2. Do you need to implement a specific protocol?

**If you selected the first option**, get [CipherSweet.js](https://github.com/paragonie/ciphersweet-js).

The documentation is [available online](https://ciphersweet.paragonie.com/node.js). `EncryptedField` is sufficient for most use cases, but the `EncryptedRow` and `EncryptedMultiRows` APIs may be easier if you have a lot of distinct fields you want to encrypt.

With CipherSweet, you don't need to *even know what a nonce/IV is* to use it securely.

Additionally, this handles `int`/`float` encryption without leaking facts about the contents through ciphertext size.

**Otherwise, you'll want [sodium-plus](https://github.com/paragonie/sodium-plus),** which is a user-friendly frontend to various libsodium wrappers. Sodium-Plus allows you to write performant, asynchronous, cross-platform code that's easy to audit and reason about.

To install sodium-plus, simply run...

```
npm install sodium-plus
```

There is currently no public CDN for browser support. This will change soon. However, you can grab `sodium-plus.min.js` from [the latest Github release](https://github.com/paragonie/sodium-plus/releases) if you need it.

```js
const { SodiumPlus } = require('sodium-plus');
let sodium;

(async function () {
    if (!sodium) sodium = await SodiumPlus.auto();
    let plaintext = 'Your message goes here';
    let key = await sodium.crypto_secretbox_keygen();
    let nonce = await sodium.randombytes_buf(24);
    let ciphertext = await sodium.crypto_secretbox(
        plaintext,
        nonce,
        key    
    );
    console.log(ciphertext.toString('hex'));

    let decrypted = await sodium.crypto_secretbox_open(
        ciphertext,
        nonce,
        key
    );

    console.log(decrypted.toString());
})();
```

The documentation for [sodium-plus](https://github.com/paragonie/sodium-plus/tree/master/docs) is available on Github.

If you'd like a step-by-step tutorial, [this dev.to article](https://dev.to/paragonie/message-encryption-in-javascript-and-php-cg9) has what you're looking for.

Comment: whats your relation to sodium projects?

Comment: it would be good to more sustained argument against WebCrypto - it seems you just linked anonymous comment saying WebCrypto was not designed with security in mind

Comment: @MaciejUrbański yeh, hes very sus.

Comment: Downvoting because there is zero indication/acknowledgement he is a maintainer (possibly head) of the project on GitHub (bias)...

Comment: @MaciejUrbański I contribute to libsodium, and led the initiative to get it into the PHP standard library. https://wiki.php.net/rfc/libsodium My relation to sodium is as a) a user, b) an independent security expert that specializes in applied cryptography.

Comment: Sodium is too much of a black box and it's documentation is awful. It's ok if the decryptor and encryptor are the same entity but for standardised encryption for transmission it's atrocious.

Answer (score 28):

Modern browsers now support the `crypto.subtle` API, which provides native encryption and decryption functions (async no less!) using one of these method: AES-CBC, AES-CTR, AES-GCM, or RSA-OAEP.

https://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/#dfn-Crypto

Comment: Out of the above options, only AES-GCM and RSA-OAEP are reasonable. :(

Comment: AES-GCM examples: https://github.com/diafygi/webcrypto-examples#aes-gcm---generatekey

Comment: crypt.subtle AES-GCM, self-contained, tested:

async function aesGcmEncrypt(plaintext, password)

async function aesGcmDecrypt(ciphertext, password) 

https://gist.github.com/chrisveness/43bcda93af9f646d083fad678071b90a

Answer (score 11):

crypt.subtle AES-GCM, self-contained, tested:

```
async function aesGcmEncrypt(plaintext, password)

async function aesGcmDecrypt(ciphertext, password)
```

https://gist.github.com/chrisveness/43bcda93af9f646d083fad678071b90a

Comment: Thanks! Dificult to find simple to use example of using native browser Crypto API. Only restriction is IE11...

Answer (score 8):

Before implementying any of this, please see [Scott Arciszewski's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58360477/1057052).

I want you to be **very careful** with what I'm about to share as I have little to no security knowledge (There's a high chance that I'm misusing the API below), so I'd be more than welcome to **update this answer with the help of the community**.

As @richardtallent mentioned in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52265545/1057052), there's support for the Web Crypto API, so this example uses the standard. As of this writing, there's a [95.88% of global browser support](https://www.caniuse.com/#feat=cryptography).

I'm going to be sharing an example using the Web Crypto API

Before we proceed, please note ([Quoting from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto)):

> This API provides a number of low-level cryptographic primitives. It's **very easy to misuse them**, and the **pitfalls** involved can be **very subtle**.
>
> Even assuming you use the basic cryptographic functions correctly, secure key management and overall security system design are **extremely hard to get right** and are generally the domain of specialist security experts.
>
> Errors in security system design and implementation can make the security of the system completely ineffective.
>
> **If you're not sure you know what you are doing, you probably shouldn't be using this API**.

I respect security a lot, and I even bolded additional parts from MDN... **You've been warned** 
 
Now, to the actual example...

---

### JSFiddle:

Found here: https://jsfiddle.net/superjose/rm4e0gqa/5/

### Note:

Note the use of `await` keywords. Use it inside an `async` function or use `.then()` and `.catch()`.

### Generate the key:

```js
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CryptoKey
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RsaHashedKeyGenParams
// https://github.com/diafygi/webcrypto-examples#rsa-oaep---generatekey
    const stringToEncrypt = 'https://localhost:3001';
    // https://github.com/diafygi/webcrypto-examples#rsa-oaep---generatekey
    // The resultant publicKey will be used to encrypt
    // and the privateKey will be used to decrypt. 
    // Note: This will generate new keys each time, you must store both of them in order for 
    // you to keep encrypting and decrypting.
    //
    // I warn you that storing them in the localStorage may be a bad idea, and it gets out of the scope
    // of this post. 
    const key = await crypto.subtle.generateKey({
      name: 'RSA-OAEP',
      modulusLength: 4096,
      publicExponent:  new Uint8Array([0x01, 0x00, 0x01]),
      hash: {name: 'SHA-512'},
      
    }, true,
    // This depends a lot on the algorithm used
    // Go to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto
    // and scroll down to see the table. Since we're using RSA-OAEP we have encrypt and decrypt available
    ['encrypt', 'decrypt']);

    // key will yield a key.publicKey and key.privateKey property.
```

### Encrypt:

```js
    const encryptedUri = await crypto.subtle.encrypt({
      name: 'RSA-OAEP'
    }, key.publicKey, stringToArrayBuffer(stringToEncrypt))
    
    console.log('The encrypted string is', encryptedUri);
```

### Decrypt

```js
   const msg = await  crypto.subtle.decrypt({
      name: 'RSA-OAEP',
    }, key.privateKey, encryptedUri);
    console.log(`Derypted Uri is ${arrayBufferToString(msg)}`)
```

### Converting ArrayBuffer back and forth from String (Done in TypeScript):

```js
  private arrayBufferToString(buff: ArrayBuffer) {
    return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(buff) as unknown as number[]);
  }

  private stringToArrayBuffer(str: string) {
    const buff = new ArrayBuffer(str.length*2) // Because there are 2 bytes for each char.
    const buffView = new Uint16Array(buff);
    for(let i = 0, strLen = str.length; i < strLen; i++) {
      buffView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return buff;
  }
```

You can find more examples here (I'm not the owner):
// https://github.com/diafygi/webcrypto-examples

Answer (score 7):

you can use those function it's so easy the First one for encryption so you just call the function and send the text you wanna encrypt it and take the result from encryptWithAES function and send it to decrypt Function like this:

```
const CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");


   //The Function Below To Encrypt Text
   const encryptWithAES = (text) => {
      const passphrase = "My Secret Passphrase";
      return CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(text, passphrase).toString();
    };
    //The Function Below To Decrypt Text
    const decryptWithAES = (ciphertext) => {
      const passphrase = "My Secret Passphrase";
      const bytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(ciphertext, passphrase);
      const originalText = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
      return originalText;
    };

  let encryptText = encryptWithAES("YAZAN"); 
  //EncryptedText==>  //U2FsdGVkX19GgWeS66m0xxRUVxfpI60uVkWRedyU15I= 

  let decryptText = decryptWithAES(encryptText);
  //decryptText==>  //YAZAN
```

Answer (score 5):

## UPDATE December 2021

use crypto api provided by **MDN Web Docs**:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto

---

### Old answer

Use [SimpleCrypto](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-crypto-js)

**Using encrypt() and decrypt()**

> To use SimpleCrypto, first create a SimpleCrypto instance with a
> secret key (password). Secret key parameter MUST be defined when
> creating a SimpleCrypto instance.
>
> To encrypt and decrypt data, simply use encrypt() and decrypt()
> function from an instance. This will use AES-CBC encryption algorithm.

```
var _secretKey = "some-unique-key";
 
var simpleCrypto = new SimpleCrypto(_secretKey);
 
var plainText = "Hello World!";
var chiperText = simpleCrypto.encrypt(plainText);
console.log("Encryption process...");
console.log("Plain Text    : " + plainText);
console.log("Cipher Text   : " + cipherText);
var decipherText = simpleCrypto.decrypt(cipherText);
console.log("... and then decryption...");
console.log("Decipher Text : " + decipherText);
console.log("... done.");
```

Comment: SimpleCrypto uses [unauthenticated AES-CBC](https://github.com/danang-id/simple-crypto-js/issues/123) and is therefore vulnerable to chosen-ciphertext attacks.

Comment: I struggled to find that nowadays we have something like `window.crypto` natively. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

CryptoJS is no longer supported. If you want to continue using it, you may switch to this url:

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/aes.js"></script>`

Comment: What is the difference between rollups and components under folder 3.1.2?

Comment: Crypto is recommending the [forge](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge) library when you enter their site.