# Encrypt a Base64 encoded image into another valid Base64 encoded image

Tags: javascript, image, encryption, encoding

I am wanting to take a currently base64 encoded image and use a short hash say "84dskh" to "encrypt" the image into another perfectly valid base64 encoded image.

The original image does not have to be base64 encoded, ultimately I want a encrypted image of the original, but have it still be  a valid image I could display in a img tag: `<img src="myimage" />`.

Preferably using javascript.

Comment: Great! What have you tried so far and where are you stuck?

Comment: Well I have tried rearranging the values of the base64 encoded string.  But I end up with an invalid string that cannot be displayed in the browser.  I know I can just "encrypt" the image, but then a image won't show up in the browser if I do that.

Answer (score 2):

To encrypt the image, you would save it as a string (there may be limits there), and then when loading the image into the HTML document, use a decrypt method. Here is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18279141/javascript-string-encryption-and-decryption). You may also find [this library](https://code.google.com/archive/p/crypto-js/) helpful (suggested within an answer).

Comment: I am not trying to encrypt per say.  More like scramble.  I want to "scramble" the image so that is unrecognizable.  Then client side in the javascript I want to "unscramble" the image when a user clicks a button.  They will go from seeing a image of pixelated junk, to the actual photo.

Comment: So effectively swap sections of the image around?

Comment: That would work, as long as the "swapped" image could still be displayed.

Comment: I'm afraid I do not know how this would be achieved, perhaps a new question entirely? Here is the only [resource](https://github.com/dantarakan/Image-Scramble) I have found with any  real relevance.