# Possible to encode an array of strings?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of strings

```js
var array = ["hello", "goodbye"]
```

and I want to encode them with a key so to decode them you'd need the key.

Would such a thing be possible without use of outside libraries

Comment: Encode as what?

Comment: ~~Check this out seems like this is what you're looking for~~ edited because I can't read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18279141/javascript-string-encryption-and-decryption

Comment: Is it possible without third party libraries

Comment: Please clarify your question stating the environment you're expecting this to run. Javascript can run almost anywhere, and the environment can have something you can use.

Comment: I am running this inside Duktape engine which doesn't allow me to use any modules that don't come with javascript