# I want to encrypt blob using SHA in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, encryption

I want to encrypt blog using SHA in javascript so that I can send the encrypted blob chunk to server and where I can decrypt it.

Comment: SHA is Hash, you can not hash then de-hash something (kinda the point of it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible.

SHA is a [*cryptographic hash* function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function), not an *encryption* function - the result is *not reversible*. See [Fundamental difference between Hashing and Encryption algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948322/fundamental-difference-between-hashing-and-encryption-algorithms/4948393#4948393) for an in-depth explanation.

Now, to *really* encrypt data in JavaScript (say with AES), there [are several options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793812/javascript-aes-encryption). Since it is hard to get cryptography and key exchange correct, using a hand-rolled encryption scheme may be no better than plain-text. As such, normally one would just use [HTTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure) to ensure the entire channel is securely<sup>1</sup> encrypted.

---

<sup>1</sup> HTTPS itself is "secure" *with* the correct negotiation options and patches.