# AES 256 Encryption in sencha touch

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch-2, aes

I wanna encrypt my password before I send it across. Is there any proper way to encrypt using AES 256 in sencha touch? If so please help me with an example

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is within the scope of Sencha Touch, since there are Javascript libraries for that. Have you tried one of them? (JSAES, Crypto-js, etc.)

See: [Javascript AES encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793812/javascript-aes-encryption)

Answer (score 0):

Use SSL (or actually TLS nowadays). There is even an SSL tag on the Sencha forums. Note the many pitfalls in creating this yourself. Forgetting to establish trust for the public key, missing authentication or integrity, incorrect session key establishment...

Note that all these points above are much more important than the key size used for AES. AES is a very useful algorithm, but it is not a magic bullet.