# What is the best way to consume api with username password?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an web application which have a mini javascript function which access API which needs username and password for authentication. I call the api like the script below.

```
var api_result = api.auth('myusername','mypassword').get({ some statement });
```

My problem is what is the best way to encrypt the username and password?

Because at chrome browser this message is being returned:

> This page includes a password or credit card input in a non-secure context. A warning has been added to the URL bar. For more information.

Comment: First - `Don't call it a password`. Second - **Hash** the **salted**-user entered value and then send it via `post` request.

Comment: To encrypt and decrypt username and password use sjcl link: https://github.com/bitwiseshiftleft/sjcl

Comment: Use AES encryption in your JavaScript code..check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793812/javascript-aes-encryption

Comment: @gurvinder372 whats the usecase of salting it on the frontend???

Comment: I have no control to the api application. is there a other way to do it? I am afraid that i cannot be authenticated due to hashed string.

Comment: @Jonasw you can recover original value from hashed un-salted value, see this example http://md5decrypt.net/

Comment: @Anthony — I suspect the warning is about your page and not the API

Comment: @gurvvinder372 whats your point?? It does not make sense to encrypt data in the frontend. A safe tunnel aka `https` is the only thing we can do to improve security.

Comment: @Jonasw https cannot prevent exposure of your password completely https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/101721/is-it-possible-for-corporation-to-intercept-and-decrypt-ssl-tls-traffic?noredirect=1&lq=1 .... Even admin shouldn't be able to recover your password.. If https was the `only thing we can do to improve security` things like salted-hash, csrf, etc wouldn't be designed at all.

Comment: @gurvinder372 READ AGAIN! The OP has no control of the backend.

Comment: @Jonasw I read `My problem is what is the best way to encrypt the username and password?` Are you sure you are reading the same question?

Comment: @gurvinder372 — It is very important that you read the *whole* question and not just cherry pick a single sentence from it to answer. (Also, please stop using the markup for code to indicate emphasis).

Comment: @Quentin I didn't gave any *answer*, did I?

Comment: @quentin thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

> This page includes a password or credit card input in a non-secure
>   context. A warning has been added to the URL bar.

You are getting that warning because your website is not using `HTTPS` and is instead using `HTTP`. `HTTPS` creates a encrypted tunnel between client and server, which prevents network sniffers from stealing important user data. [More Info.](https://www.instantssl.com/ssl-certificate-products/https.html)

Here's [proof](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/10/avoid-not-secure-warn) the warning he is getting is due to `HTTPS`.

Comment: MD5 is a hashing algorithm, it doesn't do encryption.  It is also extremely weak and should not be used anymore at all.

Comment: @LarsPeterson — Why mention it at all then?

Comment: @Jonasw — It isn't, but the way they should get encryption is to use HTTPS and not be distracted by red herrings like MD5.

Comment: @quentin yep. Hiwever as the OP edited it would be fair now to remove the downvotes ...

Comment: Re edit: "The are hundreds of ways to encrypt data. More Info." — That's an article that focuses on encrypting data stored on a hard disk. It has absolutely nothing to do with what the question is asking about.

Comment: Re edit: (You changed the more info URL): The question is asking about sending data over HTTP, not about storing it in a database. They're even using a third party API so they have no access to the database.

Comment: @Quentin _My problem is what is the best way to encrypt the username and password?_ I was not aware he was only talking about `HTTPS` until now.

Comment: @LarsPeterson — If you didn't recognise it, then putting the error message quoted in question into a search engine would have given you the context needed to understand that.

Comment: @Quentin I understood he was talking about `HTTPS`, however when I saw him ask about the username and password, I though he meant storage encryption.